# Android-Volley: Set retry policy on ImageLoader

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using **Volley** as network library on Android. I ran into *'limited functionality'* problems when using `ImageLoader`. It seems to be quite useful class with caching and stuff, so I want to continue using it. However, it doesn't give any access to the `Request` objects it creates. As a result, I'm not able to do some stuff that I can do in other cases (like setting a tag on the request for cancelling it from queue).

My current problem is - how can I set a retry policy on requests made using `ImageLoader`?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to set retry policy for ImageLoader. But you have access to all requests through volley singleton (if you use one). Try to change retry policy in addToRequestQueue method. If you need different retry specification for images and other requests - you can simply create two request queues (bad practice).